# How can I prevent OpenJPA from replacing "constant" parameters in my queries?

Tags: oracle, jpa, openjpa

I seem to have a problem with a query on a `CHAR` field that is incorrectly filtered when OpenJPA replaces my constant value with an SQL parameter.

## Example

Given this table in Oracle

```
create table PERSON (
  id char(10) not null,
  type char(3) not null,
  primary key (id)
)
```

with three different values for `type`: *WTW*, *WAI*, *V*

and the corresponding entity

```
@Entity
public class Person {
   String id;
   String type;
}
```

I use the following query from an orm.xml file:

```
<named-query name="person.v">
  <query>
    select p
    from Person p
    where p.type = 'V'
  </query>
</named-query>
```

## Problem

When I run this through an EntityManager provided by OpenJPA, the query changes to

```
select p.id, p.type
from PERSON p
where p.type = ?
```

and OpenJPA passes the value `"V"` as parameter. The previously "constant" value for `type` is now an SQL parameter. The problem lies in the fact that for the `char(3)` `type` column, Oracle will store

```
"V  "
```

and this is not equal to the value passed by OpenJPA as a parameter. Again: without parameters, i.e. just using the string in SQL that I use in JPQL, everything works just fine.

I assume OpenJPA performs this replacement in order to minimize the query cache by normalizing all queries, and I understand that this makes a big difference for a lot of people, but I think this is a problem in my case.

My question is now: how can I prevent OpenJPA from doing this replacement? I know that I won't have different permutations of this query at runtime. Is there a configuration property or a query hint that I can use?

Comment: Quick update: there is no bug in how OpenJPA handles `char` types in prepared statements. It just could not handle the column's data type, because we are using a custom `PreparedStatement` with a delegate to the actual (Oracle) statement, and the detection in org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql,OracleDictionary ([1](https://github.com/apache/openjpa/blob/2.4.0/openjpa-jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/openjpa/jdbc/sql/OracleDictionary.java#L556), [2](https://github.com/apache/openjpa/blob/2.4.0/openjpa-jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/openjpa/jdbc/sql/OracleDictionary.java#L1253)) does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides just changing the column to a `VARCHAR`, I have two workarounds that are not very nice:

1. Adapt the JPQL to `where p.type = 'V  '` ("V" followed by two spaces).
2. Use a native query which won't be optimized by OpenJPA.

In (1), I know about the underlying `char(3)` and the idea of JPQL is to abstract this away, so this goes a little bit against the idea of using JPA.

With (2) I have to rewrite this simple query just a little bit, but it just does not seem right to use a native query just to avoid problems created by good intentions of my persistence provider.